# TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object in NextAuth

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, prisma, next-auth

NextAuth.js automatically creates simple, unbranded authentication pages for handling Sign in, Sign out.So I created it like the document suggest.I created in **signin.tsx** page this function.

```js
import { getProviders, signIn } from "next-auth/react"

export default function SignIn({ providers }) {
  return (
    <>
      {Object.values(providers).map((provider) => (
        <div key={provider.name}>
          <button onClick={() => signIn(provider.id)}>
            Sign in with {provider.name}
          </button>
        </div>
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

// This is the recommended way for Next.js 9.3 or newer
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const providers = await getProviders()
  return {
    props: { providers },
  }
}

/*
// If older than Next.js 9.3
SignIn.getInitialProps = async () => {
  return {
    providers: await getProviders()
  }
}
*/
```

Also I added in **[...nextauth].ts** pages like that

```js
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin", // Displays signin buttons
    signOut: "/auth/signout", // Displays form with sign out button
    error: "/auth/error", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // Used for check email page
    newUser: null, // If set, new users will be directed here on first sign in
  },
```

But I take error like this.**TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object**. I also changed `NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000/api/auth`  to
`NEXTAUTH_URL=http://localhost:3000`, but it is not fixed

I also added signin function in callbacks

```js
  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      const isAllowedToSignIn = true;
      if (isAllowedToSignIn) {
        return true;
      } else {
        // Return false to display a default error message
        return false;
        // Or you can return a URL to redirect to:
        // return '/unauthorized'
      }
    },
```

this is the route it takes me after clicking on signing button

```
http://localhost:3000/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A3000%2F
```

Also that is my **options** object

```js
const options = {
  providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],
  adapter: PrismaAdapter(prisma),
  secret: process.env.SECRET,
  session: {
    // Use JSON Web Tokens for session instead of database sessions.
    // This option can be used with or without a database for users/accounts.
    // Note: `strategy` should be set to 'jwt' if no database is used.
    strategy: "jwt",
    // Seconds - How long until an idle session expires and is no longer valid.
    maxAge: 30 * 24 * 60 * 60, // 30 days
    // Seconds - Throttle how frequently to write to database to extend a session.
    // Use it to limit write operations. Set to 0 to always update the database.
    // Note: This option is ignored if using JSON Web Tokens
    // updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
  },
  jwt: {
    // You can define your own encode/decode functions for signing and encryption
    // if you want to override the default behaviour.
    // encode: async ({ secret, token, maxAge }) => {},
    // decode: async ({ secret, token, maxAge }) => {},
  },

  // You can define custom pages to override the built-in ones. These will be regular Next.js pages
  // so ensure that they are placed outside of the '/api' folder, e.g. signIn: '/auth/mycustom-signin'
  // The routes shown here are the default URLs that will be used when a custom
  // pages is not specified for that route.
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/pages
  pages: {
    signIn: "/auth/signin", // Displays signin buttons
    signOut: "/auth/signout", // Displays form with sign out button
    error: "/auth/error", // Error code passed in query string as ?error=
    verifyRequest: "/auth/verify-request", // Used for check email page
    newUser: null, // If set, new users will be directed here on first sign in
  },

  // Callbacks are asynchronous functions you can use to control what happens
  // when an action is performed.
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/callbacks

  callbacks: {
    async signIn({ user, account, profile, email, credentials }) {
      const isAllowedToSignIn = true;
      if (isAllowedToSignIn) {
        return true;
      } else {
        // Return false to display a default error message
        return false;
        // Or you can return a URL to redirect to:
        // return '/unauthorized'
      }
    },

    async jwt({ token, account }) {
      // Persist the OAuth access_token to the token right after signin
      if (account) {
        token.accessToken = account.access_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    async session({ session, token, user }) {
      // Send properties to the client, like an access_token from a provider.
      session.accessToken = token.accessToken;
      return session;
    },
  },
  // Events are useful for logging
  // https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/events
  events: {},

  // You can set the theme to 'light', 'dark' or use 'auto' to default to the
  // whatever prefers-color-scheme is set to in the browser. Default is 'auto'
  theme: {
    colorScheme: "dark",
  },
};
```

Comment: Probably the result of `await getProviders()` is empty. What do you get when you look the following url `/api/auth/providers`

Comment: @JapMul TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object error again. I don't know if it is problem with typescript.

Comment: Ok, might be something wrong with the `providers` key in `[...nextauth].ts`. Does the error disappear when you just put in `providers: []`?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/auth/error?error=undefined when make providers:[] and This page could not be found error

Comment: Ok, but what is the response of `/api/auth/providers` when you set `providers` to an empty array? The response should be an empty json response.

Comment: http://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers gives me {} empty object when I make providers:[] instead of   providers: [
    EmailProvider({
      server: process.env.EMAIL_SERVER,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
    }),
    GithubProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GITHUB_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GITHUB_SECRET,
    }),
    GoogleProvider({
      clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
    }),
  ],

Comment: Ok, that's a good thing. And does the signIn page render as well? Without any buttons of course because the response is empty, but it should render. If that's the case then the error is somewhere in the build-up of your providers array.

Comment: yes when I make it http://localhost:3000/ I have a navbar with signing button

Comment: Ok, can you add the construction of your providers array to the question?

Comment: @JapMul I attached it

Comment: @sayinmehmet47, Did you find any solution? I am facing the same error!

Comment: Same! Sometimes the /providers response is an empty JSON object

Comment: You might have been doing the same mistake that I did and that is placing the `signin.tsx` under `pages/api/auth/signin.tsx` when you should be placing the page under `pages/auth/signin.tsx`. It might or might not be the issue, but it looked exactly what I was going through, so perhaps check that it's in the correct path.